# WPF: Image binding with property of DataContext in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I try to set binding for `Image` according [such examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.urisource.aspx). My XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="imgPhoto" x:FieldModifier="public" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
     VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding Path=Photo, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

But I get exception (look below) in constructor of my window. Why it happens?

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred   HResult
>   =-2146233087   Message = "Initialization of "System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage" caused an exception.": row
>   number "57" and a line item in line "34".

The `Photo` is the property of `Employe` item, which will a source for `DataContext`. It property will a `"pack://application:,,,/myImages/male.png"`string value. I will set it property for my `Window` instance. But I got such exception in `Window`'s constructor earlier than I initialize this property via my value. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You can binding directly to `Image.Source` your `Photo` property:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=Photo}" />
```

And `Photo` property should look like this:

```
"/YourProjectName;component/myImages/myPhoto.png";
```

Of course png file should have `Build Action` set to `Resource`.

On msdn you have good article about this, below is link to it.

[Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)